# Large mysql table stuck optimizing table

Tags: mysql, optimization

So I am optimizing a table on a unused server. The table has 40+ million records with a size of  about 10GB. The optimize has been running for about 5 days. The .TMD file is 9.115 GB the .MYD file is 9.136 GB. The .TMD file has a last modified date of 5 days ago which is about when i started the process. Also i got a warning from cpanel saying that the /tmp directory(4GB) is 100% full. I started this not thinking about the space of the /tmp (new server) My question is could this process still be running and using space else where or is it frozen because of the lack of space?

I don't want to interrupt it and crash the table if i don't have to. I have not seen the size of any files change within the past couple hours. Should i just stop it, repair the table, and add more space to the /tmp dir then restart the optimization?

Any info and suggestions would help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would definetly stop it and restart once you have more space. If it has been running **5 DAYS** with no sign of change in the last few hours, then it is definetly frozen.

And if your .tmd and .myd are 9+ gigs, then your /tmp directory should be at least a little larger, since it is possible that the files are all stored in the RAM and at the end are pushed out, you could have ran out of space a long time ago and are just running around in circles ... you know, a endless loop. (but thats just coming from a systems hardware engineer's perspective)

=)

Comment: Thanks! can i just change the tmp dir location in mysql temporarily to  a larger partition to do the optimization then change it back or is there something particularly special about the /tmp dir

Comment: That is a good question, to tell you the truth i do not know, I mean something as powerful as mysql SHOULD allow that however I am still experimenting with the DB myself =) teoretically speaking any old dir should do, the /tmp is technically just a dir of its own (only it works with the RAM and not the HDD)

Comment: I found this surfing the internet, idk if it can help you but give it a try, tell me how it goes =) 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/change-existing-datadir-path-in-mysql

Comment: Do you know if there would be any problems with increasing the /tmp to  say 30GB?

Comment: Oh God i am super late with this one, just saw the message now so sorry, you probably figured it out by now but no there should be no problems with upgrading to 30GB :)